# mvn command without anything throws build failure error

Tags: maven

[image]Okay, I am totally new to maven and just installed one.

I have configured JAVA_HOME so that when I type mvn -version, the message shows with

```
  Apache Maven 3.3.9
  Maven home: /user/share/maven
  Java version: 1.8.0_131, ...
  Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

And I just typed "mvn" out of curiosity, which throw an error back at me.
Now when I am trying to clean using mvn clean, 
I get all the errors related to build failure.

Can someone tell me where to go next from here?

Comment: I think the problem is that I typed mvn even without any 'pom.xml'  let me post error msg quick,

Comment: Yes, that'll be it. Even `mvn clean` won't work without a pom. You'll get "[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory" or similar.

Comment: then I guess I don't even have anything to clean?  so my first meaningless 'mvn' command didn't do much harm either?

Comment: No harm at all. It did nothing.

Comment: Thanks, then is it normal to see the build failure error message still when I type 'mvn clean' ?  I will post it quickly

Comment: Yes. The message is clear: the build failed because there is no POM in /home/xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a pom.xml file in your current working directory. Put this into a new pom.xml and you'll see the error change to something more descriptive:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```